# How do you reinstall an app's dependencies using npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a simple way to reinstall *all* packages that my app depends on (i.e. they are in my apps node_modules folder)?

Comment: `npm rebuild` might also help some issues with native dependencies

Comment: In case it helps others: If you're just trying to reinstall one package, `npm update <packageName>` works great

Answer (score 890, accepted):

The easiest way that I can see is delete `node_modules` folder and execute `npm install`.

Comment: Agreed; assuming you've created a `package.json` file for your app.

Comment: Beware that running `npm install` after removing the `node_modules` directory can result different versions of dependencies defined in `package.json` being pulled down. If you require very specific versions of dependencies for your app, be careful and look into `npm shrinkwrap` or checking in your `node_modules` directory to source control.

Comment: @smithclay I've defined the explicit version of the packages in my app's package.json, so that should be fine, right?

Comment: @vadim I was doing some testing on the behavior of `npm install` and it always reinstalls dependencies and upgrades packages to latest versions as permitted by package.json. So removing `node_modules` folders is not needed unless you think its corrupted. Is there a reason you think it should be removed? However, if the intent is to remove any packages that are extraneous then you could execute `npm prune` instead

Comment: @himanshu you are right `npm install` upgrades all modules to package.json state. But the question is _how to reinstall all packages_. So they may be corrupted or may need to rebuild the binary parts after upgrade node.js verison.

Comment: @trusktr not necessarily. locking down specific versions will ensure *your* deps don't change, but you dependencies' dependencies could still change

Comment: @jasonkarns This is if I remove my node_modules directory and run `npm install` right? So nothing will happen if my dependency numbers haven't changed and I try upgrading (not having removed `node_modules`)? Or will it?.. On another note, this could be a pain for modules in npmjs.org that rely on latest dependencies (no version numbers). Each time the user installs my package it could pull in different versions of the package's dependencies, even if he pulls a specific version of my package? If so, there's something inherently wrong with that.

Comment: @jasonkarns It says here that name and version are required for npmjs packages: https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html. I haven't tested it, but I'm going to assume that not requiring both a name and version would make things very hectic. I'll try it next time I get to developing my Node.js stuff.

Comment: @trusktr what do you mean "upgrading without deleting node_modules"? my original comment was that, yes, transitive dependencies can change without your own package.json changing. (if node_modules is removed and then run `npm i`)

Comment: @jasonkarns I totally agree with what you said if you make a project on your hard drive adhoc, but it's not true if your package is going in npmjs.org. npmjs.org packages require version numbers in package.json. That's all I meant. :)

Comment: @trusktr I've never once suggested omitting version numbers in package.json.  Transitive dependencies can change even with package versions specified. Say I depend on module A@0.1.0. Module A depends on module B using ~0.4.0 (or 0.4.x or >=0.4.0). In this case, doing `npm update`  (or `npm install` after removing node_modules) will get the latest version of module B that satisfies module A's package.json. So you could end up with B@0.4.9. Only way to lock down transitive deps is with `npm shrinkwrap`.

Comment: @jasonkarns Oh, so we are allowed to put things like `0.4.x` or `>=0.4.0`in a package.json of a package that we put on npmjs.org?

Comment: @jasonkarns Oh, in the "dependencies" section of a package's package.json. That is quite nasty!

Comment: I updated _node.js_ & _npm_ from an outdated version after already using `npm install` on a project.  

The following did not work:
`npm install`
`npm update`
`npm rebuild`

But what did work is what @VadimBaryshev recommended:
**1.)** delete `node_modules` folder
**2.)** `npm install`

Comment: I love workflows that the accepted process is "Delete the world then rebuild from scratch".  Of course if some jackass unpublishes his packages when you do this...

Answer (score 141):

The right way is to execute `npm update`. It's a really powerful command, it updates the missing packages and also checks if a newer version of package already installed can be used.

Read [Intro to NPM](http://smalljs.org/package-managers/npm/) to understand what you can do with npm.

Comment: But if there is no newer package then this won't do anything, right? I'm trying to *force* reinstall even if the package is already at latest version.

Comment: If there are no missing packages, then it will check if it can use latest versions of packages (including dependencies of the packages) listed in package.json . So, in essence it will upgrade packages if possible. But it will not reinstall. If you want to do it using commands you can execute `npm uninstall <package_name>` to uninstall specific package or execute `npm uninstall` to uninstall all packages.

Comment: I tried doing just `npm uninstall` without specifying a package but that throws an error.

Comment: Do you have package.json in the folder directory where you executed this? If you are uninstall global package then you will need to add -g

Comment: Yeah, package.json is there. It just doesn't work. It says `npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/trusktr/src/myApp/nodeapp/node_modules:`.

Comment: Are you executing this inside node_modules folder? if so can you try one level up?

Comment: Yeah, I tried in the parent of the `node_modules` folder. No luck. I'm using Node 0.8.11.

Comment: This also works for modules installed with "npm install path/to/some/lib" if the package.json version is changed.

Comment: The link you provide is dead, can you please supply a new one? (I found [this](https://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm) but I'm not sure it's acceptable to change to it)

Comment: No, that's not the right way and it's not an answer to the question. The question is how to reinstall and not how to update to latest version. I need to downgrade.

Comment: For anyone trying to update a git url dependency, open the package.json, copy the name and do "npm uninstall [NAME]", and then once uninstalled, do CTRL + Z and CTRL + S to bring back(change the hash if desired) the dependency in the package.json file and then do "npm install".

Answer (score 113):

You can do this with one simple command:

```
npm ci
```

Here's an excerpt from [`npm ci` documentation:](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci)

> In short, the main differences between using `npm install` and `npm ci` are:
>
> - The project must have an existing `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in `package.json`, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - `npm ci` can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a `node_modules` is already present, it will be automatically removed before `npm ci` begins its install.
> - It will never write to `package.json` or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

Comment: This answer adds some info regarding `npm ci`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014814/10788155

Comment: ci does not work for global packages that are to be installed with -g option

Comment: @RajaNagendraKumar The question is about reinstalling app dependencies, not global packages.

Comment: In short: do ```npm ci``` if you want to reinstall your node_modules, but don't want to have your package-lock.json updated

Answer (score 106):

Most of the time I use the following command to achieve a complete reinstall of all the node modules (be sure you are in the project folder).

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

You can also run `npm cache clean` after removing the `node_modules` folder to be sure there aren't any cached dependencies.

Answer (score 83):

`npm` updated the CLI command for `install` and added the `--force` flag.

```
npm install --force
```

The `--force` (or `-f`) argument will force `npm` to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.

See [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: My experience is that this doesn't work. The docs say that it does, but it simply doesn't.

Answer (score 41):

As of npm cli **v6.5.0** you can use the backronym:

```
npm clean-install
```

##### Sources:

https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.5.0
https://github.com/npm/cli/commit/fc1a8d185fc678cdf3784d9df9eef9094e0b2dec

Answer (score 20):

You can use the [reinstall module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reinstall) found in npm.

After installing it, you can use the following command:

```
reinstall
```

The only difference with manually removing `node_modules` folder and making `npm install` is that this command automatically clear npm's cache. So, you can get three steps in one command.

**upd:** `npx reinstall` is a way to run this command without globally installing package (only for npm5+)

Comment: @g00glen00b I've edited so that it now does include useful information without hyperlinks

Answer (score 9):

Delete node_module and re-install again by command

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm i
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows you can use

```
(if exist node_modules rmdir node_modules /q /s) && npm install
```

which removes `node_modules` directory and performs `npm install` then. Removal before install assures that all packages are reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step to re install node modules and update them

works even if node_modules folder does not exist. now execute the following command synchronously. you can also use "npm update" but I think this'd preferred way

```
npm outdated // not necessary to run this command, but this will show outdated dependencies

npm install -g npm-check-updates // to install the "ncu" package

ncu -u --packageFile=package.json // to update dependencies version in package.json...don't run this command if you don't need to update the version

npm install: will install dependencies in your package.json file.
```

if you're okay with the version of your dependencies in your package.json file, no need to follow those steps just run

```
 npm install
```