# ng serve not detecting file changes automatically

Tags: angular

I need to run `ng serve` every time when any changes made to the source files.I have no error in the console.

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.2
Node: 8.9.1
OS: linux ia32
Angular: 5.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.2-c3d7cd9
@angular/cli: 1.6.2
@angular/material: 5.0.3-e20d8f0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.2
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Comment: Did you try ng serve --watch ?

Comment: Yes. But it didn't resolve my problem

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: Try this way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42534127/1191125

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Most of the times in Linux, `ng serve` or `ng build --watch` doesn't work if the directory doesn't have sufficient permissions.

The solution is either to provide the necessary permissions or to use  `sudo` instead.

**UPDATE**

watch flag in `ng serve` is actually redundant as it is the default option. Credit to @Zaphoid for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Then, please accept this as the answer, which will help others who read this question in the future

Comment: @Mawg Instead of using sudo. Which set of permission the files should have?

Comment: Depends on the user which is running, maybe as much as `a+x`, but I warn against using permissions, rather than `sudo`. `sudo` is for a single command, whereas changing permissions changes them forever, which seem a greater security leak.

Comment: fkn permissions. Thanks dude!

Comment: `--watch` shouldn't be neccesary, as it is a default, see https://angular.io/cli/serve. So @T. van den Berg 's answer was actually more precise!

Comment: That's a good catch @Zaphoid! The answer was actually targeting both serve & build as people tend to face the same problem in case of `ng build`. However, I completely missed the fact that `ng serve` actually watches by default. Thanks!

Comment: I gave the directory a+rwx but still has the same issue what is exactly necessary permissions shuold I provide ?!

Comment: What are the relevant permissions required to grant to the user? Ideally, administrative development should not be done wherever possible.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Since ng serve is used almost exclusively for development purposes, I think a security concern shouldn't be much of an issue (if the case is in a prod state, then we need to reconsider)

Comment: Outdated Answer not working anymore 2023

Comment: @user1034912 So `ng serve` is not detecting your changes even after providing necessary folder permissions or using sudo?

Answer (score 156):

```
ng serve --poll=2000
```

Working fine in linux and windows

Comment: what does is it mean (--poll)

Comment: Can confirm this works. Running linux subsystem on WIndows 10 (Ubuntu) with VS Code running on Windows.

Comment: Works on ubuntu 18.0.4

Comment: That worked on ubuntu 18.04. can you please describe its reason ?

Comment: For me works fine! But, i don't understand the cause "ng serve" don't reload the project.

Comment: Working on WIndows7

Comment: yes great. thanks.. this is also worked for me. i'm using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Works in WSL(Windows 10)

Comment: @HD.. For what it's worth --poll allows for changing the behavior of what filesystem is checked by defining a polling frequency.  By default, ng will check "native" which may not  work as expected when using WSL1/2, shared file systems, etc.  see https://angular.io/cli/serve and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930195/what-is-the-function-of-poll-flag-in-cli.

Comment: Works for me. I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 9 in docker.

Comment: works fine with ubuntu 20.04/windows10 linux subsystem, i tried many solutions, only this one refresh the server correctly on save, i don't know why but its works :) thx you

Comment: this one worked for me on elementary OS 5.1 based on Ubuntu 18.04 . i also tried to set the permission as suggested in some ans but didn't work .

Comment: The --poll flag takes an optional argument, which specifies the time interval in milliseconds for polling file changes. For ng serve --poll=2000 means sets the polling interval to 2 seconds

Answer (score 84):

Consider that, when having a large number of files, there is a Limit at **INotify** Watches on Linux. So increasing the watches limit to 512K, for example, can solve this.

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sudo sysctl -p --system
```

Note that the previous causes an in-memory change that you will lose after restart.

However, you can **make it persistent**, by executing:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system
```

---

As a reference, you can check: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8313#issuecomment-362728855 and 
https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu 14
-
"echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system"

Comment: you can use this commmand to check/test the current watch limit `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

Above answer is a totally complete answer but here is a link with little more description
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit

Comment: worked fine. it worth noting that some IDEs (like JetBrains Webstorm) use inotify to track file changes as well. so, keep it in mind if you open 5 projects and than run ng serve.

Answer (score 26):

Because of, The system that detects changes can't handle so much watches by default.

And the solution is to **`change the amount of watches`** it can handle (the maximum amount of files that will be in the project) you must **`run this command`**:

```
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

The problem with inotify is reseting this counter every time you restart your computer.

Comment: echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

Answer (score 19):

In your project dist folder is own by root

Try to use `sudo ng serve` instead of `ng serve`.

**Another solution**

When there is having a large number of files watch not work in
 linux.There is a Limit at INotify Watches on Linux. So increasing the
 watches limit

```
//When live server not work in linux

sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sudo sysctl -p --system

ng serve //You can also do sudo **ng serve**
```

Answer (score 8):

Only need to run **sudo** ng serve to resolve the issue.

Comment: Nice workaround but why having to do so is the real question.... running as root isn't the best practice...

Answer (score 5):

This may help if it is the same problem I had.
Trying to use `ng serve` and `ng build --watch` sometimes worked but mostly they were not watching for code changes and I thought it was something to do with `ng`.

Then I remembered a problem I had a while back with
[inotify watches](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)

I ran this on my Ubuntu machine and it seems to have kicked in and watching code changes:

**echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system**

credit goes to [Scott Smith](https://github.com/scottasmith)

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend changing SO parameters. 
I've experienced some (lag) issues after changing fs.inotify.max_user_watches parameter since you will have other services running...

The "ng serve --poll=2000" is a good solution but you will probably forget this parameter...

Investigating: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli 
I'd done the following solution.

Changed de angular.json with poll parameter

```
"serve": {
   "builder....
   "options": {
        "browserTarget": "xkcd:build",
        "poll": 2000
   }
   ...
```

Works on My Machine :D

Comment: Thank you! 

This is ad hoc way to run it without modifying config files: `npm run ng serve -- --poll=2000`. 

This is not as nice as file change detection, but *just works* on my machine (corporate flavor of Ubuntu 18.04). I have max_user_watches set to 524288, but `ng serve` still fails detecting changes after some time. I have better things to do than investigating this, so this solution is just what I need.

Comment: Thanks!, just added "poll":2000 in angular.json & working well

Answer (score 3):

try this.
If you do like this you don't need to fire always any command
You need to fire only one time

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, check your code for syntax errors - particularly on `index.html`, or parts of your code you recently edited just before this auto update broke. Syntax errors will break this auto update functionality in Angular.

In my case, I had multiple projects open in separate VS Code windows. On all my other projects, `ng serve` worked as expected: it auto updated on save. But on one project it would require a manual refresh to update. It ended up being because I had html comments outside of the defined HTML area of the template (so, the HTML comments came before `<!doctype html>`. So it was invalid bc it's HTML syntax outside of an HTML area.

I erased the comments and bam, auto update started working again (after one more manual refresh).

So go through `index.html` or other parts of your code you recently edited before this broke and one by one, cut sketchy parts out, do a refresh in the browser, then come back to VS Code and make a change, save and see if it auto updates.

Comment: Other errors with the Template may also prevent it from working correctly. In my case, I had custom component expecting an `@Input()`, but the attribute was blank, like this: `[myInput]=""`. Filling it with a value restored `ng serve`, no manual refresh required.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that the dist/ folder in the project was owned by root. That is why `sudo ng serve` does see the changes when `ng serve` does not.

I removed the dist/ folder `sudo rm -R dist/` and rebuild it as current user by starting the dev server `ng serve` and all worked again.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem on a new Linux Ubuntu install and noticed I was getting an error about 'too many watchers for limit' in VSCode at the same time. I followed the instructions to fix it in VSCode and it also fixed the issue with ng watch. More info here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

I noticed people suggesting `sudo` to run watch. This is a dangerous game, you are giving npm packages root access to your system. If your permissions are correct, my issue could be your fix since the limit is per user, and by running as sudo, you are running as root instead of your current user that is past the limit (running a watch heavy ide like vscode or atom on ). If for some reason you have the wrong permissions, set them properly to your user / group with `chown`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use `chown` instead of running `ng serve` with `sudo`, which should be avoided by all means!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, using `sudo ng serve` seemed to "solve" the problem unsatisfactorily. Using `sudo` is not satisfactory IMO.

I checked my INotify count versus my default limit (8192) using:

`lsof | grep inotify | wc -l`

The value returned by the above command was way less than the limit.  So the INotify solution didn't seem to apply to my problem.

I also checked permissions and ownership, both seemed ok, comparable to another project that worked.

Out of frustration I restarted VS Code.  Basically I closed all instances, I had two running and re-opened both following which the problem went away.

I am leaning towards a possible bug somewhere. This is something to consider before turning your system inside out.  Fortunately/Unfortunately this problem hasn't occurred again, I'll dig deeper if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too.

```
sudo ng serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing the `sudo ng serve` command is a bad practice. You have to change the `npm` permission so that every time if you have to install some `npm packages` you don't have to use `sudo`.

[This link](https://www.competa.com/blog/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/) can solve how to change npm permission to the current user and after following through this steps after you set the npm permission you can remove the `node_modules` folder from your project directory and use `npm install`. After completion of packages installation you can run `ng serve` and you don't have to do `sudo ng serve` every time you want to run your angular project.

Answer (score 1):

My answer may not be useful. but I search this question because of this.

After I bought a new computer, I forget to set auto save in the editor. Therefore, the code actually keep unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work for me:

```
ng serve --watch
```

Try :

```
sudo ng serve
```

this worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

for window -

```
c:\>ng serve --open
```

For Linux -

```
$sudo ng serve --open
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to leave my case here, just for reference. In my case, the problem was on the system permissions. I used a shared folder inside a VM as a repo. I had no other message like permission denied or something. Tried everything and then I just realized that I was using a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Giving full permission for the project folder worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Mac it was fixed by granting Read/Write permission to logged on user to /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 0):

System configuration:
Angular CLI: 17.0.4,
Node: 18.18.0,
Package Manager: npm 9.8.1,
OS: darwin x64

**Update angular.json with poll parameter**

```
"serve": {
      "builder....
      "options": {
        "poll": 2000
      }
    }
```

Above solution resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by deleting package-lock.json before running npm i (the problem was only in a certain project)

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the server worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

For me what worked was:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

And then

`ng serve`

Answer (score -1):

use sudo before ng serve it will work. In terminal type
: 'sudo ng serve'

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the IDE did the job for me. I'm using VS Code

Answer (score -1):

If you are using vsCode, maybe you forgot to enable `Auto Save`.

Go and select `File > Auto Save` to enable auto save.

The problem will be solved.