# Why doesn't Angular CLI recognize the current Node.js version?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nvm

Angular is telling me that my Node.js version is too old for my Angular version:

***sudo ng serve***

```
You are running version v4.2.6 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9 and greater.

Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.
```

I updated my Node.js version to the latest:

***node --version***

v11.9.0

***npm --version***

6.7.0

***nvm --version***

0.34.0

Even after updating  Node It still gives me the warning. This problem only happens when I use ***sudo*** before the command.

***Edit 1***

As requested:

***ng --version***

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 11.9.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Comment: can you post output of ng --version from your project directory?

Comment: Added the output to the question.

Comment: Why are you using sudo ?

Comment: Because ***ng serve*** was not automatically updating and I read in another question that It could be that I needed to give It more permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092880/ng-serve-not-detecting-file-changes-automatically

Comment: for your watch issue, have you tried changing the amount of watches? answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092880/ng-serve-not-detecting-file-changes-automatically#answer-49045489
seems legit reason :P

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik It started working again. When I close and then open VS Code It also works, but the detected changes only occur in HTML or Typescript files.

Comment: that's interesting. It should work. for which file format its not working ? anyway you can checkout this thread too :) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8168#issuecomment-355455249

Comment: and for your sudo ng serve problem, can you check if output of which node & sudo which  node are same ?