# Laradock doesn't watch Angular ng build --watch

Tags: angular, docker, build, angular7, laradock

I'm building my Node14.6 Angular7.2 project inside a laradock container.
First of all, I went to laradock.io and made a git clone from laradock to my project

```
git clone https://github.com/Laradock/laradock.git
```

After that, the only relevant file from laradock I've changed was laradock/workspace/Dockerfile because I need angular/cli@7.2.2:

```
[ ${INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI} = true ]; then \
        npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2.2 \
```

So, with only that little change, I started my containers using bellow code:

```
docker-compose up workspace apache2 mariadb
docker exec -it 9210e8d6ab25/bin/bash
ng new my-project
cd my-project
ng build --watch
```

This is a print to prove the well behave of the container by generating the projetc's build
[image]
[image]
The project is builded ok but when I start to develop the code with VS Code the build isn't beeing updated.

Do someone have any clue to resolve it?

Comment: Where you say "I'm running this command" you have a PNG file instead of a command line; how do you run it?  Where are you updating the code?  Do you rebuild the underlying Docker images when you do make a change?  Can you provide a [mcve] including any relevant configuration files or Docker setup?

Comment: I edited my question. If you follow what I said above, you're gonna be able to reproduce the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: [ng serve not detecting file changes automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092880/ng-serve-not-detecting-file-changes-automatically/50448576)

I only had to add

```
--poll=2000
```

and the build command should be like:

```
ng build --watch --poll=2000
```