# Typescript / Angular Not A Function Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and typescript and am confused by this error thrown when the function below is called in ngOnInit() :

> TypeError: this.jsCall.getRemoteJASON is not a function. (In
> 'this.jsCall.getRemoteJASON()', 'this.jsCall.getRemoteJASON' is
> undefined

The component imports a service which facilitates a JSON call:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JSONService } from './Services/json.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Week7Ex1JSON';
  studentDetails : string [];

  constructor (private jsCall : JSONService){}

ngOnInit(){

  this.jsCall.getRemoteJASON().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.studentDetails = data.students;//retruns an array
    console.log(this.studentDetails);
  });
}
  
}
```

This is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JSONService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }


  getRemoteJASON() : Observable <any>{
    return this.http.get("https://jsonblob.com/api/00f6ea4d-1d46-11eb-ab21-8f2b7998e4cf");
  }
}
```

The correct imports and dependencies appear to be in place so I'm at a loss as to the cause of the error.

Versions:
Angular CLI: 8.3.8
Node: 10.13.0
OS: darwin x64

Any input appreciated.

Comment: can you share your `app.module.ts`

Comment: try restarting the angular dev server: `ng serve`

Comment: Your code is working for me, try restarting your dev server.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dancingbush

Comment: Thanks restarting the server did the trick - @robert can you  post comment as answer , any idea what causes this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092880/ng-serve-not-detecting-file-changes-automatically/50448576) it is related.