# Cannot find module 'react-dom/test-utils' from 'act-compat.js'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I cannot seem to resolve why I'm receiving this error: Here are my configs:

```
lang-js
react - 15.3.1
react-dom - 15.3.1
react-testing-library - 6.0.0
jest - 23.6.0

lang-js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from 'react-testing-library';

afterEach(cleanup);

test('loads and displays ', async() => {

})
```

I commented on an open [GH issue](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/315) on the `react-testing-library` page. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `npm` or `yarn`?

Comment: (1) Could you post your package.json file (because it seems important according to your answer).
(2) Could you post your solution as answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 2):

This may have happened if something got modified or deleted in your `react-dom` dependency package.

### Using yarn

You can [verify that already installed files in node_modules did not get removed, reinstalling any missing files](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install) by using:

```
npm install --check-files
```

That should help you restore `react-dom` to what it should be.

If that doesn't work, you can always try to completely remove and reinstall all of your packages. From your project root folder, try:

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install
```

### Using npm

First, you can try just to install `react-dom` again. That might solve your problem:

```
npm install react-dom
```

If that doesn't work, then you can try to [reinstall all of your packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866494/how-do-you-reinstall-an-apps-dependencies-using-npm) to get a fresh copy.

From your project root folder, try:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: I removed my `node_modules` folder, and that didnt fix it. The fix was to add `^` to my react dependencies:
react - ^15.3.1,
react-dom - ^15.3.1

Comment: @eagercoder I'm glad you found a workable solution to your issue! Happy coding!